# Editing tag explorer.js

Tags: javascript, css

I'd like to remove the letters that are displayed at the left of the tags produced by [`tag-explorer.js`](https://github.com/Tyriar/tag-explorer). How can I achieve this?

Here's the live website: https://ewelinawoloszyn.github.io/Research/research_03.html

Here's the script:

```
// The container to hold the tags.
tagContainer = document.querySelector('.tag-container');
// An array of objects where the `'element'` property is the article element (to
// be hidden), and the `'tags'` attribute is an array of tags on this article.
// Articles do not necessarily have to be the <article> element.
articles = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('article')).map(function (article) {
  return {
   'element': article,
   'tags': [].slice.call(article.querySelectorAll('.tags li')).map(function (tag) {
     return tag.textContent;
   })
  };
});
// Create an array of tag names to be available for filtering.
tagNames = ['Public Finance', 'Access', 'Data','Money','Open Source'];
// Initialise tag-explorer.
tagExplorer(tagContainer, articles, tagNames);
```

Here's the desired output -- I'd like the red crossed letters to be removed:
[image: Here's the desired output]

Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: *"remove letters before tags"*: I don't understand what that means. Can you give a concrete example of what you want to achieve: input and desired output?

Comment: Sure how do I add image in Stackoverflow @trincot?

Comment: When you edit your question there is a button bar at the top of the input area. Click the icon with the landscape (next to the `{ }` icon).

Comment: I looked at the image you posted as an answer (which you should not do, by the way), but it really leaves to much for us to guess: what part of that image is what is different from what you get now? Where is the data that results in this page? Can you just focus on the part that does not work? Make it something that we can easily reproduce.

Comment: Ok @trincot I've updated the question.You can find there my desired output image.I hope that's clear now?

Comment: Data that results in the page can be seen here:https://ewelinawoloszyn.github.io/Research/research_03.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide these letters by altering some styles in your file [`style.css`](https://ewelinawoloszyn.github.io/Research/style.css):

Change this:

```
.tag-container .letter-header {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 1em;
}
.tag-container button {
  background-color: #AAA;
  color: #fff;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 1px 6px;
}
```

to this (changes are marked with `/* .. */`):

```
.tag-container .letter-header {
  display: none;  /* <!-- modified */
  padding: 0 1em;
}
.tag-container button {
  margin: 0 5px;       /* <!-- added */
  background-color: #AAA;
  color: #fff;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 1px 6px;
}
```

The first change causes the letters not being rendered. Without further change this would make the tags (buttons) stick to each other. The second change deals with this, and introduces an empty space between them.

Comment: Great thank you it worked! And can I ask how to add extra margin to 'Access' button only? Add 1st child element? .tag-container button 1st child { ?

Comment: You could do that with `li:first-child`, like this: `.tag-container.show-all li:first-child button { margin-left: 10px }`, so it will only apply to the `button` that is in the first `li` among other `li` siblings.

Comment: Thank you again are you fammilliar with d3.js @trincot?

Comment: You're welcome. No, I am not particular familiar with d3.js, but I have answered some questions that involved it in the past.

Comment: Please @trincot have a look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40418310/creating-marker-in-d3-js-and-leaflet Many thanks in advance